# JumpList and ClickOnce - is this combination possible?

Tags: .net, windows-7, clickonce, jump-list

I have a WPF application which uses a JumpList (Recent only). Everything works perfectly until I deploy it using ClickOnce - the JumpList simply does not show (BTW, it does not show as well when running under VS debugger.

Anybody knows if it is possible to have JumpList working from a ClickOnce deployed app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the ClickOnce product lead if this was possible, and I regret to tell you that it's not.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested a JumpList with .NET 4, Windows 7, and ClickOnce. It worked perfectly on the first try.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as the OP, but I didn't manage to do it just like him. When I start my application from Visual Studio I can register *tasks* using the *JumpList* class, but when I start the application after I've installed it using *ClickOnce* no tasks show up on the on the Windows jump list. Can you elaborate on your answer? Provide links? A working example? Hints? (I'm using .NET 4 and Windows 7 too.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) instead of the jumplist capabilities that are built in to WPF. You will still have some hoops to jump through ([editing your copy of the Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824697/jumplist-and-clickonce-is-this-combination-possible)) but it will be possible at least.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the Windows API Code pack at all. It's buggy, the API is bad and it seems unmaintained. If you are looking for something that also works in .NET 3.5 go for Microsoft.Windows.Shell instead, the API is almost 100% compatible with System.Windows.Shell http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx